# PHP Search string in multiple files pdf and get name this files

Tags: php, file

I have write script to the search string in pdf files. I used script from this link:  [link](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html).
I have problem, because my script not search in all files pdf, only search in first file (sorted by name)

My script:

```
foreach (glob("storage/cvs/*.pdf") as $file) {
    // $files = 'storage/cvs/d08540965a_2017-12-06.pdf';
    $this->pdf2text->setFilename($file);
    $this->pdf2text->decodePDF();
    $convert2Txt = $this->pdf2text->output();

    if (stripos($convert2Txt, $query) !== false) {
        echo $resultQuery =  "tak ".$file."</br>";
    } else {
        echo $resultQuery =  "nie znaleziono ".$file."</br>";
    }

}
```

And I don't know how I can get name files where found string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```
$dir = "/path/to/your/directory/"; // Set your directory path here
if (is_dir($dir)){                // Check its a directory
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){     // Open the directory 
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){  // Read the files
            if (substr($file, -3)=='pdf') {  // Check filename ends 'pdf'
              // Your code here
```

`$file` will be set as the filename